tailwind - different background images for breakpoints
I want to have a different background image for each breakpoints. i.e mobile, tablet and desktop
Below is the default tailwind background image. I am not sure how to add other background images for tablet and desktop
<main class="mx-auto">
    <section class="min-h-screen bg-cover bg-no-repeat border-b border-gray-50 border-y-gray-300" style="margin-top: -56px;
        background-image: url({{url('assets/images/herobanner/testmale.jpeg')}});"></section>
</main>

In Response to the comments below
I tried doing the following
<section style="margin-top: -56px;"
            class="min-h-screen bg-cover bg-no-repeat border-b border-gray-50 border-y-gray-300
             bg-[url({{url('assets/images/herobanner/test.jpeg')}})] md:bg-[url({{url('assets/images/herobanner/test_small.jpeg')}})]">

Its still not working. Please note that I am using Laravel blade.
I checked my console and it is indeed showing the correct URL for the image, so not sure why its not showing.
UPDATE-
Thanks you to @kylepg. I got it to work.
This worked for me.
.main-img {
    background-image: url('/storage/images/smallpicture.jpeg');
   
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .main-img {
        background: url('/storage/images/smallmale.jpeg');
        
    }
}


@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .main-img  {
        background: url('/storage/images/female.jpg');
      
    }
}


You could add in a <style> tag and use CSS media queries:
// Default background for mobile
.element {
    background-image: url('{{ url('assets/images/herobanner/mobile.jpeg') }}');
}

// Tablet breakpoint (768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .element {
        background-image: url('{{ url('assets/images/herobanner/tablet.jpeg') }}');
    }
}

// Desktop breakpoint (1024px and up)
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .element {
        background-image: url('{{ url('assets/images/herobanner/desktop.jpeg') }}');
    }
}

Just be sure to add a class or ID to <section> that you can use as a CSS selector, and swap that in for .element above.

Hello @kylepg. thanks for your answer. i am a bit confused how to do the last part. i. adding the element to the section. Could you kindly explain this to me

@PaulKendal In order to apply the CSS in the above example to your <section> element, you would add an element class like so: <section class="element ...">. I used element as a generic example but you should use a different word that's a bit more descriptive (i.e. image-section)

hi @kylepg. thank you so much for your help. I want to mark your answer as correct. However, I was not able to get it to work when I used the URL method. i had to use relative path. The rest of your code worked. Could you possible change your code to relative paths so that i can mark it. That way, we help others

To add a background image using Tailwind, you can use arbitrary values. See Documentation here. To be able to apply different images at different breakpoints, all you have to do is add the different breakpoint prefixes sm, md, lg, etc.
Here's a code sample using Unsplash Images:
<div class="h-screen bg-cover bg-[url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620389876845-1e807ce5692d&w=1080)] md:bg-[url(https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1661685126470-8421243def69w=1080)]">
</div>

Let me know if you need further assitance. :)

Just want to note that this approach only works with hardcoded image URLs. Since OP is using Laravel Blade to dynamically insert the URLs, Tailwind won't be able to generate the proper CSS for those classes.

hello @kylepg - i am a bit confused by what you just said. Could you kindly explain a little further

@PaulKendal Sure thing. This answer suggests using Tailwind arbitrary classes for background images at different breakpoints. While this could work, you would need to include the complete URLs directly in the class names (like bg-[url(https://example.com/image.jpg)]). However, since it appears you’re using a url() function to determine the image URL, this method won’t work (Tailwind needs the complete URL in the class so that it can be included in the corresponding CSS class definition). Therefore, you should use plain CSS as I suggested in the other answer.
